# Parse-server save photo error Retryable writes is not available

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

I want to save photo but i had this error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1k69.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/retryable-writes/#prerequisites) the retryable writes feature is only available in MongoDB 3.6+ with feature compatibility version set to 3.6+.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of back4app mongoDB URI. I changed it my local URI. It works.